# Does controllers get created whenever models are created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I created model for user in ruby on rails using scaffold.
Then I got to know that when I saw controller's folder of the project I would find usercontroller.rb file created ? Does this means that whenever model is created controllers are created with it ?

Comment: No controller doesn't get created whenever model is created. It happens only for scaffolding. if you don't use scaffold generator you need to create them separately.

Comment: when you run a scaffold command it generates relevant model, controller and view files for you. If you are not using the scaffold you can generate them separately one after the other

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the model creation that does it, it's the scaffolding.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/getting_started.html

Section 6 of that document describes what is generated during scaffolding. The scaffolding process creates a number of files, controller being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

`rails generate scaffold` will generate a model, controller database migration, and views.

Here is a list of the generators that Rails provides:

- `assets`
- `controller`
- `generator`
- `helper`
- `integration_test`
- `jbuilder`
- `mailer`
- `migration`
- `model`
- `resource`
- `scaffold`
- `scaffold_controller`
- `task`

The [Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) can provide you with additional information on the command line tools.